# Make two columns like a map data type in excel

Tags: database, excel, maps

This question may be a little hard to understand but I will try my best. Basically, I have an excel spreadsheet with 2 columns and around 30,000 rows. One of the columns tells me the unique ID of each family and the other tells me how many people are in each family. I'm trying to get a sum of all the people in the families. The issue is, there are many duplicates on this sheet. It would be easy if they were already separated in to unique values and I would just take the sum of the second column. What I want to do is somehow map those two columns together, the first being an ID and the second being a value. That way I could just grab all the unique pairs in the map (rather than just the IDs or just the number of people in each family) and after I get that number, take the sum of the unduplicated number of people in each family.

Hopefully that all made sense. If you have any experience in excel and know how to accomplish this or think of maybe a better approach to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case of duplicates IDs, do you have a specific criteria over which corresponding value you want to keep?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC You should be able to use Excel's built in `Remove Duplicates` function for exactly this. It's on the Data tab. In VBA it'd be [Range.RemoveDuplicates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-removeduplicates-method-excel)

If you can't get it to work on value pairs, use a string CONCATENATE to put both values (with a unique separator) in a third column and dedup just that column. Then you can split them again to get the original list.

If you don't want to edit the original list, copy the data to a temporary sheet first.